# How add language by command-line?

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, command-line, system-language

I want to make a bash script which add language in System after re-install

I don't want to use GUI (I know how to do it)

May be anybody now how to do it by command-line ?

P.S.
Might I didn't say clearly

I don't want to change locale, I want to add language in keyboard. So after that I can change print language. In the end I need to have opportunity to switch between languages (for example Eng, Rus...)

Comment: Have a look here : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't want to change local. I want to add language to switch them

Comment: I see.  Retracting close vote.

Comment: Do you want to install an additional user interface language, or do you want to add a keyboard layout?

Comment: I don't know how exactly it called. 
I know how explain. I want to add language in "Text Entry Settings -> Input source to use:"